# The output of print(stdout.read()) in Python shows all formatting symbols

Tags: python, pycharm, stdout

I'm new to Python and experimenting with it for network automation. My first experiment is simply to show the output of the "show version" command on a Cisco switch. My code is as follows:

```py
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("10.0.0.1", username="lab", password="lab")
(iin, stdout, stderr) = (ssh.exec_command("show ver"))
print(stdout.readlines())
```

And the output is:

```
['Cisco IOS Software, C3560E Software (C3560E-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE9, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)\r\n', 'Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport\r\n', 'Copyright (c) 1986-2014 by Cisco Systems, Inc.\r\n', 'Compiled Mon 03-Mar-14 22:28 by prod_rel_team\r\n', 'Image text-base: 0x00003000, data-base: 0x02800000\r\n', '\r\n', 'ROM: Bootstrap program is C3560E boot loader\r\n', 'BOOTLDR: C3560E Boot Loader (C3560X-HBOOT-M) Version 12.2(58r)SE1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)\r\n', '\r\n', 'SWITCH1 uptime is 2 hours, 8 minutes\r\n', 'System returned to ROM by power-on\r\n', 'System image file is 
etc.....
```

So it is showing the \r and \n symbols but not creating new lines etc.

I am using PyCharm to do this and, again, I am a complete newcomer to it, so it might be a setting in there rather than a programming thing. I've clicked on the "Soft wrap" button incidentally; prior to doing that it displayed the entire output on a single line.

How do I get it to display properly?

Comment: Your printing out a `list`, which is not the same thing as a `str`. Perhaps `print(''.join(stdout.readlines()))` produces the output you're lookng for?

Comment: Your question title says `read` but your actual code has `readlines`. The latter returns a list, not a string.

Comment: Thanks President James K. Polk. print(''.join(stdout.readlines())) produces exactly the output I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a common thing many programmers encounter when working with network devices. As kaya3 mentioned, `readlines()` returns a list, so you can iterate through the list, decode the raw data, and strip any extra characters:

> **NOTE** - Tested in Centos 7, using Python 2.7 and GNS3, with a simulated Cisco 3745 router.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("10.0.0.1", username="lab", password="lab")
(iin, stdout, stderr) = (ssh.exec_command("show ver"))

# New code:
output = stdout.readlines()
for line in output:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Cisco IOS Software, 3700 Software (C3745-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(25d), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2010 by Cisco Systems, Inc.

...

151K bytes of NVRAM.
65536K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash (Read/Write)

Configuration register is 0x2102
```

Always mind your carriage returns and line feeds; each manufacturer is different (and even some devices by the same manufacturer use different line endings!). Some will only accept `\r`, some will only accept `\n`, some will only accept `\r\n`, and some will accept `\r` or `\n` at different times.

Good luck coding!

**PS** - Just saw President James K. Polk response after posting this. Both `print(''.join(stdout.readlines()))` and `print(stdout.read())` work as well.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, much appreciated.  

I found that 
for line in output:
    print(line.decode().strip())

produced the following error:

"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?"

whereas 
for line in output:
    print(line.strip())

produced the desired output

I don't understand why at the moment but I'll go with it for now.

Comment: It's a Python 2.7 thing. You are right; if you use `line.decode()` in Python 3+, you will get the `AttributeError`.